# Difference between Iterator and Listiterator?

Tags: java, list, iterator, set, listiterator

```
Iterator ite = Set.iterator();
Iterator ite = List.iterator();

ListIterator listite = List.listIterator();
```

We can use `Iterator` to traverse a `Set` or a `List` or a `Map`. But `ListIterator` can only be used to traverse a `List`, it can't traverse a `Set`. Why?

I know that the main difference is that with iterator we can travel in only one direction but with `ListIterator` we can travel both directions. Are there any other differences? And any advantages of `ListIterator` over `Iterator`?

Comment: in addition to Peters answer I'd recommend you read a chapter in thinking in java about iterators with all nice examples there

Answer (score 159, accepted):

The differences are listed in the Javadoc for [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html)

You can

- iterate backwards
- obtain the iterator at any point.
- add a new value at any point.
- set a new value at that point.

Comment: And the reason why you can't do that with a `Set` is simple: There is not "current point": Elements have no index and there is no usefull way you can add an element "before" or "after" another one.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey **obtain the index at any point** - Is it about methods *previousIndex()* and *nextIndex()* ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow check java.util.List#listIterator(int)

Comment: @kilonet instead of **obtain the index at any point**, should it be phrased like "obtain the iterator at any point" to avoid confusion ?

Answer (score 43):

There are two differences:

1. We can use Iterator to traverse Set and List and also Map type of Objects. While a ListIterator can be used to traverse for List-type Objects, but not for Set-type of Objects.

   That is, we can get a Iterator object by using Set and List, see here:

   By using Iterator we can retrieve the elements from Collection Object in forward direction only.

   Methods in Iterator:

   1. `hasNext()`
   2. `next()`
   3. `remove()`

   ```
   Iterator iterator = Set.iterator();
   Iterator iterator = List.iterator();
   ```
2. But we get ListIterator object only from the List interface, see here:

   where as a ListIterator allows you to traverse in either directions (Both forward and backward). So it has two more methods like `hasPrevious()` and  `previous()` other than  those of Iterator. Also, we can get indexes of the next or previous elements (using `nextIndex()`  and `previousIndex()` respectively )

   Methods in ListIterator:

   1. hasNext()
   2. next()
   3. previous()
   4. hasPrevious()
   5. remove()
   6. nextIndex()
   7. previousIndex()

   ```
   ListIterator listiterator = List.listIterator();
   ```

   i.e., we can't get ListIterator object from Set interface.

Reference : - [What is the difference between Iterator and ListIterator ?](http://kirankumarjava.blogspot.in/2013/06/what-is-difference-between-iterator-and.html)

Comment: This looks like it is largely cut-and-pasted from http://kirankumarjava.blogspot.com/2013/06/what-is-difference-between-iterator-and.html. You must always acknowledge the original author.

Answer (score 28):

> Iterator is super class of ListIterator.

Here are the differences between them:

1. With `iterator` you can move only forward, but with `ListIterator` you can move backword also while reading the elements.
2. With `ListIterator` you can obtain the index at any point while traversing, which is not possible with `iterator`s.
3. With `iterator` you can check only for next element available or not, but in `listiterator` you can check previous and next elements.
4. With `listiterator` you can add new element at any point of time, while traversing. Not possible with `iterator`.
5. With `listiterator` you can modify an element while traversing, which is not possible with `iterator`.

**Iterator look and feel:**

```
 public interface Iterator<E> {
    boolean hasNext();
    E next();
    void remove(); //optional-->use only once with next(), 
                         dont use it when u use for:each
    }
```

**ListIterator look and feel:**

```
public interface ListIterator<E> extends Iterator<E> {
    boolean hasNext();
    E next();
    boolean hasPrevious();
    E previous();
    int nextIndex();
    int previousIndex();
    void remove(); //optional
    void set(E e); //optional
    void add(E e); //optional
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following is that the difference between iterator and listIterator

iterator :

```java
boolean hasNext();
E next();
void remove();
```

listIterator:

```java
boolean hasNext();
E next();
boolean hasPrevious();
E previous();
int nextIndex();
int previousIndex();
void remove();
void set(E e);
void add(E e);
```