# What is the difference between iterator and listIterator()?

Tags: java, list, iterator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [difference between Iterator and Listiterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977992/difference-between-iterator-and-listiterator)

Recently,while I was goint through javadocs, I found two methods in List interface : **iterator()** and **listIterator()**. Apart from different return type, what are the other differences between these two methods? 
Below is the java doc for both method.

```
// List Iterators
/**
 * Returns a list iterator over the elements in this list (in proper
 * sequence).
 *
 * @return a list iterator over the elements in this list (in proper
 *         sequence)
 */
ListIterator<E> listIterator();
```

And

```
/**
 * Returns an iterator over the elements in this list in proper sequence.
 *
 * @return an iterator over the elements in this list in proper sequence
 */
Iterator<E> iterator();
```

Comment: The same question was asked 8 mins earlier. :P

Comment: Have you looked at the Javadoc for `Iterator` and `ListIterator`?

Comment: @PéterTörök Actually the ListIterator javadoc alone gives you the differences as its a sub-type. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) is a subclass which extends [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

A [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) allows traversal in both directions, rather than just checking if there are more elements (`hasNext()`), and getting the next one (`next()`).  It maintains a cursor position and calls to `next()` and `previous()` will alter the position and return relevant values.  [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) also allows the addition (`add(E e)`) of entries, and the setting of entries (`set(E e)`) to the underlying list (Unlike Iterator, which just allows removing).

Answer (score 4):

With ListIterator, you can traverse forward and backward over a list, while you can traverse only forward with Iterator. On the other hand, ListIterator is only used for lists but Iterator is used for map, set, and list.

Answer (score 1):

[ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html):

A ListIterator has no current element; its cursor position always lies between the element that would be returned by a call to previous() and the element that would be returned by a call to next().

Answer (score 1):

[ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) is just an extension of plain [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), allowing you to traverse the list in either direction, modify the list during iteration, and obtain the iterator's current position in the list.