# What is the benefit of using Iterator instead of ListIterator for ArrayList?

Tags: java, optimization, iterator, listiterator

From what I understand, ListIterator provides much more functionality than Iterator for lists. If so, why use Iterator at all? Is there an optimization or performance factor to it as well?

Comment: You can refer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17939167/3226981

Comment: Only lists have a ListIterator. Sets, and collections only have an iterator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Iterator and Listiterator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977992/difference-between-iterator-and-listiterator)

Answer (score 0):

Generally the less your code knows about other parts of code and data structures the better. The reason is simple: this simplifies the modification.

Indeed, `Collection` is more powerful than `Iterator`, `List` is more powerful than `Collection`.

But `Iterator` can be obtained from a lot of data structures, so if you are using Iterator that you get from (for example) list you can than change your code and get iterator from (for example) database without changing code that works with iterator.

Comment: "more powerful than Iterator" - Did you mean `Iterable`?

Comment: No, I mean `Collection`. Iterable is just an accessor to `Iterator` with additional compiler magic named `for(:)`

Comment: `List` is a `Collection` is an `Iterable`, hence `List` "is more powerful than" `Collection` just as `Collection` "is more powerful than" `Iterable`...

Answer (score 0):

Use the ListIterator to express the requirement to iterate in a specific order. Use the Iterator to express that order does not matter.

Generally I think that the use of iterators makes code difficult to read. I don't know your use case but in most cases it makes sense to use the enhanced for loop or a functional approach like Java 8 streams instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you need functionality of `ListIterator` then you can use it. At the same time, you restrict yourself to operating on `List`s at that specific place.

Now, if you implement some really `List`-based operation, you actually *want* to operate on `List`s only, so maybe that's no restriction for you.

If, however, you don't really need the special funtionality of `ListIterator` but an `Iterator` is sufficient, then prefer using the plain `Iterator`; this enables you to operate not only on `List`s but on any data structure which implements `Iterable`, including all kinds of `Collection`s. This makes your code more generic and flexible to use.